# Works in JSFiddle not in browser and '$ is not a function

Tags: wordpress, var, jsfiddle

I have this little snippet of code that works great in JSFiddle and in a Chrome extension.  On clicking "button" it blurs the ID "content".

```
var dimthis = $("#content")
var button = $("button")
button.on("click", () => {
dimthis.toggleClass("alt")
});
```

I've been through quite a few of the similar question that say to add $(document).ready(function(){
before and this  });`
at the end giving this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var dimthis = $("#content")
var button = $("button")

button.on("click", () => {
dimthis.toggleClass("alt")
});
});
```

That has worked for me before but not helping with this little ditty of code.

When I add the second set of code I get "$ is not a function error"

Thanks in advance for the help.

***** ANSWER (since I can't post answers for some reason) ******

This is a Wordpress site and Wordpress uses `jQuery.noConflict();`

So, in Wordpress, *$ is undefined* ergo the message "$ is not a function error"

Instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

in Wordpress you need to use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

What worked is putting it in the child-themes funtion.php like this:

```
function load_dimmer_script(){
    ?>
    <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var dimthis = $("#content")
    var button = $("button")
 
    button.on("click", () => {
    dimthis.toggleClass("alt")
    });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'load_dimmer_script' );
```

What this does is this:  If the menu toggle is defined as a button, when the menu is clicked the content of the page (#content) gets blurred.  Click menu toggle again, it goes unblurred.

See [nova-energy.net](https://nova-energy.net)

Here's the one piece of CSS needed:

```
#content.alt {
    filter: blur(4px) !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the JS code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // your code
)};
```